# Message Broker XMLNSC parser: how to avoid quotes escaping?

Tags: xml, messagebroker, ibm-integration-bus

When using XMLNSC parser of Message Broker it normally escapes double quotes in XML, like below:

```
<MyElement>Some "Text" inside</MyElement>
```

becomes

```
<MyElement>Some &quot;Text&quot; inside</MyElement>
```

One of the customers claims that such escaping is a real problem for them.

In the same time such escaping is not obligatory, as far as I can see in XML specification, so I tried to find a way to skip it, but out of luck.

Any idea about how it could be done? Or a workaround may be?

PS

We run version 10 (which is known as Integration Bus), but I remember that behaviour is the same for older versions (since 6th)

Comment: I just tried this on Broker V8, with an MQ Input configured with XMLNSC, and cannot see the escaping neither in the debuger nor when I write the message back to MQ. Where do you see the escaping?

Comment: I had this problem and in my case it was due to the fact that I created a user defined property and wrongly enclosed the property with " (double quotes) and used the property inside a XML mapping and the double quotes were escaped.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that escaping of quote characters within a tag value is optional. Message broker and IIB always escape a quote character, whether or not the escaping is required. The escaping does not change the data; any properly-written XML parser will decode the value and return the original string to the application. Your customer is either using a very badly-written application, or they have misunderstood the situation.
If you *really* need to avoid the escaping, you can use the XMLNSC.AsIsElementContent field type. Do this at your own risk, though. And you should explain to your customer that this is a fault in their application, and not a defect in IIB.